How can I check for duplicates and move them into another list?
I'm trying to avoid duplicates on a list while making sure those duplicates are moved into another list.
Here's my code so far:
fileExt = ['json','csv','excel','parquet','csv','xml','pkl','json','json','csv','docx']

fileExtList = []

duplicatesList = []

for ext in fileExt:
    if ext not in fileExtList:
        fileExtList.append(ext)
    if ext in fileExtList and ext not in duplicatesList:
        duplicatesList.append(ext)

The output I'm looking for should be something like this:
print(fileExtList) #Output: ['json','csv','excel','parquet','xml','pkl','docx']

print(duplicatesList) #Output: ['json','csv']

duplicatesList should also have no duplicates. Just those values which had been written twice in fileExt.
Note: I'm quite new to Python and programming itself.

Try using collections (Link is to an online Python interpreter w/ example code)

Is something wrong with your code?

Just reverse the steps in your for block so you add to your duplicate list before checking your fileExtList and it should work fine:
for ext in fileExt:
    if ext in fileExtList and ext not in duplicatesList:
        duplicatesList.append(ext)
    if ext not in fileExtList:
        fileExtList.append(ext)

Otherwise your if ext in fileExtList condition will ALWAYS be true since the first step was to add it to fileExtList.
Thanks to @nocomment's very excellent suggestion: You could also change the second original step to an elif so it only fires if the first if fails:
 if ext not in fileExtList:
     fileExtList.append(ext)
 elif ext not in duplicatesList:
     duplicatesList.append(ext)

The results will be the same, but it keeps python from having to run a superfluous step.

Better don't reverse but use elif.

Better yet, use collections module, but I get the sense that this is a homework assignment so it's really more of a "learn to think through the logical flow of your program" type of exercise.

Which is why I suggested what I suggested. It's straightforward, reflects the order in which things are happening, and is close to theirs. In case it's not clear, I'm talking about if ext not in fileExtList:         fileExtList.append(ext)     elif ext not in duplicatesList:         duplicatesList.append(ext).

Gotcha! I did misunderstand. Do you mind if I add to the answer?

Feel free to. If I minded, I wouldn't/shouldn't  suggest it :-)
